# Gauss-Jordan Method

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, self-learning, gaussian-elimination

I keep getting the wrong set of solutions can someone help me. I know that when using the Gauss-Jordan method, the rules that I must follow can be applied in a variety of different procedures then why do I keep getting a different result, I reduce this matrix from its previous form on the right to its reduced system also known as the reduced echelon form that is on the left side.
$$
        \left[\begin{matrix}
        5 & -5 & -15 & 40 \\
        4 & -2 & -6 & 19\\
        3 & -6 & -17 & 41 \\
        \end{matrix}\right] =
        \left[\begin{matrix}
        1 & -1 & -3 & 8\\
        0 & 2 & 6 &-13\\
        0 & -3 & -8 & 17\\
        \end{matrix}\right]
$$

$$
 \left[\begin{matrix}
        1 & -1 & -3 & 8\\
        0 & 2 & 6 &-13\\
        0 & -3 & -8 & 17\\
        \end{matrix}\right]=
 \left[\begin{matrix}
        1 & -1 & -3 & 8\\
        0 & 1 & 3 &\frac{-13}{2}\\
        0 & -3 & -8 & 17\\
        \end{matrix}\right]
$$

$$
  \left[\begin{matrix}
        1 & -1 & -3 & 8\\
        0 & 1 & 3 &\frac{-13}{2}\\
        0 & -3 & -8 & 17\\
        \end{matrix}\right]=
 \left[\begin{matrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{3}{2}\\
        0 & 1 & 3 &\frac{-13}{2}\\
        0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{-5}{2}\\
        \end{matrix}\right]
$$
$$
  \left[\begin{matrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{3}{2}\\
        0 & 1 & 3 &\frac{-13}{2}\\
        0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{-5}{2}\\
        \end{matrix}\right]=
 \left[\begin{matrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{3}{2}\\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
        0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{-5}{2}\\
        \end{matrix}\right]
$$
Therefore my solution set should be: $$(\frac{3}{2}, 1, \frac{-5}{2})$$ But the solution to the problem from the book I am studying from, states that this is the solution. $$(-\frac{5}{2}, −6, -\frac{11}{2})$$

What rules should I consider and how can I follow all the rules of the Gauss-Jordan method without getting an incorrect set of solutions.

Here is the equation:

5x − 5y − 15z = 40

4x − 2y − 6z = 19

3x − 6y − 17z = 41

Comment: What rules did you apply? Did you mix row and column operations?

Comment: Well I started by first reducing the top row by multiplying it by -1/5

Comment: Neither your solution, nor solution from the textbook seem to be correct. Unless you typed it wrong here. See [this](http://bit.ly/1rp4zQZ).

Comment: @user3593705 Nothing wrong in that. Could you update your answer with all the steps you used?

Comment: @M.Vinay Yeah just give me a couple of minutes and I'll rework it, I've been at this problem all day it's driving me crazy.

Comment: The Echelon form of the augmented matrix will be $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & -3 & 8 \\ 
0 & -1 & -2 & 4 \\ 
0 & 0 & 2 & -5
\end{pmatrix} $

Comment: I edited to show my steps.

Comment: @user3593705 $-13/2 = -6.5 \ne -5$

Comment: Actually I got 5 from adding $$R_1 to R_2$$ as in -8 + 13 = 5

Comment: Then the first element of $R_2$ should be $1$ (after the addition).

Comment: Okay found my first bug in my solution. I am going to divide Row 2 by 2.

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't add $R_1$ to $R_2$ at all, that defeats the whole purpose of the systematic method of elimination. Once you've made the first column elements to $0$ in lower rows, don't use upper rows, because then the elements would become non-zero again.

Comment: Can you display what you mean.

Comment: I edited it again with some updates.

Comment: Actually they are both correct the solutions but how? The answers make all statements true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first mistake is in the fourth matrix. The entry in row 2, column 4 should be $-\frac{13}{2}$ and not $-5$.

**EDIT**
Seems that you have silently corrected this in the meanwhile.

BTW: Formally, your equality signs are not correct. Use, for example, arrows instead.

Comment: Okay I'll use arrows.